# How to change default position of RGL window in R?

Tags: r, rgl

I am using Windows 11. I am plotting 3D stuff in R. When I want to see how the map is looking, an RGL windows pops up. However, it opens in the top left corner of the screen and the X button is hidden, like if the RGL window was too high. I have to make some extra steps to click on "X" if I want to close it or just `rgl::rgl.close()`

[Title bar is not visible by default, I have to open the Task View to be able to close it by clicking in "X"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQO4E.png)

I think my problem would be solved if the default window would open in the center of the screen or even a little lower. How do I change its default position?

Comment: You should post reproducible code to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us how you opened the window.  If you're using `open3d()`, just specify `windowRect`.  If you're opening the windows automatically, you can put `windowRect` in the `r3dDefaults` variable, e.g.

```
r3dDefaults <- list(windowRect = c(466L, 208L, 1019L, 659L))
```

If you want a different position, then move the window to the position you want, and run `par3d("windowRect")` to see the coordinates you've chosen.

Edited to add:

After looking more closely at the code image you posted, I think you're using the `rayshader` package to open the `rgl` window.  That package overrides a lot of `rgl` defaults and the proposed solution may not work.  That's why you should always post reproducible code when you ask a question:  I would have checked my answer before posting.